# Energy Equation of an ideal gas in expanding space-time

Tags: thermodynamics, general-relativity, space-expansion, ideal-gas, plasma-physics

Short question:

If the energy equation of an ideal plasma is written as follows:

$\begin{equation}
\frac{\mathrm{d}p}{\mathrm{d}t}=-\Gamma p\nabla\cdot v-\left(\Gamma-1\right)\left( \nabla\cdot q-\Pi\left(\nabla v\right)
    \right),
\end{equation}$

with p the pressure, $\Gamma$ the adiabatic index, v the velocity, q the heat flux through the boundary, and $\Pi$ the viscous stress tensor ($\Pi\left(\nabla v\right)$ the volumetric viscous heating rate), how would this look like in an expanding universe (preferably in a 3+1 notation)?

$\\$

$\\$

Long derivation and explanation of above formula:

If we are in the Lagrangian frame (a volume element co-moving with the fluid), the energy flow across the surface $-\nabla\cdot q$ plus the viscous heating rate $\Pi\left(\nabla v\right)$ must equal the heat input rate per unit volume $\rho\frac{\mathrm{d}Q}{\mathrm{d}t}$:
\begin{equation}
    \rho\frac{\mathrm{d}Q}{\mathrm{d}t}=-\nabla\cdot q+\Pi\left(\nabla v\right),
\end{equation}
with $Q$ the heat unit per mass and $q$ the heatflux through the boundary.

The viscous heating rate $\Pi\left(\nabla v\right)$ comes from the viscous stress tensor $\Pi$ which is of the form
\begin{equation}
    \Pi= \begin{pmatrix}
            0 & a & b \\
            a & 0 & c\\
            b & c & 0
        \end{pmatrix},
\end{equation}
with, $a$, $b$, and $c$ scalars.

Lets assume there is no heat loss through the surface, but volume elements can interchange heat, so that the first law of thermodynamics \begin{equation}
    \mathrm{d}Q=p\mathrm{d}\left(\frac{1}{\rho}\right)+\mathrm{d}e,
\end{equation}
with $p\mathrm{d}\left(\frac{1}{\rho}\right)$ the PV-work per unit mass and $de$ the change in energy per unit mass can be substituted in above equation. We find
\begin{equation}
    p\rho\frac{\mathrm{d}\left(\frac{1}{\rho}\right)}{\mathrm{d}t}
    +\rho\frac{\mathrm{d}e}{\mathrm{d}t}=-\nabla\cdot q+\Pi\left(\nabla v\right).
\end{equation}

The factor $\frac{\mathrm{d}\left(\frac{1}{\rho}\right)}{\mathrm{d}t}$ can be rewritten:
\begin{align}
    \frac{\mathrm{d}\left(\frac{1}{\rho}\right)}{\mathrm{d}t}&=\frac{-1}{\rho^2}\frac{\mathrm{d}\rho}{\mathrm{d}t}\\
    &=\frac{-1}{\rho^2}\left(-\rho\nabla\cdot v\right)\\
    &=\frac{1}{\rho}\nabla\cdot v.
\end{align}
With this we can express the rate of change of energy per unit volume as
\begin{equation}
    \rho\frac{\mathrm{d}e}{\mathrm{d}t}=-p\nabla\cdot v-\nabla\cdot q+\Pi\left(\nabla v\right).
\end{equation}
Again, we can use the continuity equation, but this time to rewrite
\begin{equation}
    \rho\frac{\mathrm{d}e}{\mathrm{d}t}=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\left(\rho e\right)+\rho e\nabla\cdot v,
\end{equation}
which leads to
    \begin{equation}
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\left(\rho e\right)=-\rho e\nabla\cdot v-p\nabla\cdot v-\nabla\cdot q+\Pi\left(\nabla v\right).
\end{equation}

For an ideal gas we have
\begin{equation}
\rho e= \frac{p}{\Gamma-1},
\end{equation}

which leads to the equation on the top.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe just take

$\frac{dQ}{dt} \rightarrow \frac{1}{a^3(t)}\frac{d}{dt}(a^3(t) Q)$

where $a(t)$ is the scale factor?

$\dot a/a = H$, the Hubble constant.

The reason is that the first equation looks like a 4-divergence, and a divergence with metric $g$ is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{g}} \partial_\mu( \sqrt{g} f^\mu)$.

Not sure about my answer, especially because there is no time derivative of $\rho$ and because I am confused about Lagrangian coordinates.